# Ajax fetching all usernames returns all usernames as one long string combined

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

I am fetching data from my database whith php and receive the response with ajax.

When I try to show all results, ajax reponse gives me all usernames combined as one long string back instead of an array which I can loop thru.

what am I missing?

my ajax code is per below:

```
   function userquery(){


    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;

    var userq = "%"+user+"%";


      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {   // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
               if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {


                      var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);



               for(var i = 0; i <  response.length  ; i++){

                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += response["user"];


               }

               }
               else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                  alert('There was an error 400');
               }
               else {
                   alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
               }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "userquery.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("user=" + userq);
 }
```

Comment: what is the type of `response` id in dom (Is it div/span or any input element)?

Comment: @B.Desai it is a div, maybe lack of knowledge, but I really do not know what am I missing, Jquery is no option for me... as I want to learn vanilla Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your element is `div` so to separate each user and add it to new line. Add `<br>` at end. Change your code

```
 document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += response["user"];
```

to

```
document.getElementById("response").innerHTML += response["user"]+"<br>";
```

Comment: tried that allready now it tells me "undefind" in every new row for every user and it puts out way more "undefind" then users exist in my table

Comment: now this error occurs SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data    for line  var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);